# AWS CLI uploading data to S3 (read timeout=60)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having issues uploading data to S3 when I use the cp command:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive /mydir/ s3://amazonbucket
```

I get the error (for some datasets and not others, and when I retry the errors happen on different datasets):

```
upload failed: mydir/myfile to s3://amazonbucket/myfile HTTPSConnectionPool(host='amazonbucket.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

Is there a way to fix this? How can I set the timeout to be longer?

(I was hoping to post this on the AWS forums but can't seem to be able to post there)

Comment: The 1st check here can be the region , did you specify the correct region while uploading your file?

Comment: I didn't specify the region explicitly in my command line. 

However, as I mentioned - while some of the datasets failed, others did not and DID successfully get uploaded to the bucket - so I'm assuming the region worked for them (since I can see them on S3 in the console).

Comment: Can you please tell me the size of the files you are attempting to upload that are not working?

Comment: 100 Mb - ~1 Gb @XavierHutchinson

Comment: Can you please try using s3 sync (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) I personally have experienced this to be a bit more reliable.